# Grunt Build Aborted Due to Warnings

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-jasmine, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm new to angular and I'm working with Yeoman scaffolded apps and Grunt. I successfully created a few Grunt builds earlier on in the project but now when I do:

```
Grunt build
```

I get the following message:

I'm not sure how to interpret the command line output which is below. Can anyone advise me on how to debug this?

```
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
>> 39 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Configuration changed for concat, uglify, cssmin

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

    Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Copied 2 files

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2015-05-27 05:22:41 UTC)
    loading tasks  191ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 19%
    copy:styles    817ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 81%
    Total 1s

    Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task
    Total saved: 0 B

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2015-05-27 05:22:41 UTC)
    loading tasks  245ms  ▇▇▇ 5%
    svgmin:dist     4.4s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 95%
    Total 4.6s

    Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
    Minified 20 images (saved 330.53 kB)

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2015-05-27 05:22:41 UTC)
    loading tasks  243ms  ▇▇ 3%
    imagemin:dist   9.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 97%
    Total 9.5s

Running "autoprefixer:server" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/bs-custom.css created.
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/bs-custom.css created.
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.

Running "concat:generated" (concat) task
File .tmp/concat/scripts/vendor.js created.
File .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js created.

Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
>> 2 files successfully generated.

Running "copy:dist" (copy) task
Copied 10 files

Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/404.html, dist/index.html to update script refs
✔ bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-cookies.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-resource.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-touch.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-cookies.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-resource.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-touch.min.js

Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task

Running "uglify:generated" (uglify) task
>> 2 files created.

Running "filerev:dist" (filerev) task
Revved 24 files

Running "usemin:html" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "usemin:css" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Warning: dist/index.html
Parse Error: <head "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.requesting-page.com">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.93e62615.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.07ad5b86.css">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="ang2050515App">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">benpearce.info</a>
          </div>

                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="HeaderController">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="#/">Apps</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact')}"><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view="">

    </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Ben Pearce</p>
      </div>
    </div>-->


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!--<script>
       document.domain = "google.android.apps.maps";
    </script>-->
    <script src="scripts/vendor.c832fa75.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/scripts.be38e076.js"></script>
</body>
</html> Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-05-27 05:19:55 UTC)
wiredep:app           6.6s  ▇▇ 3%
concurrent:dist   2m 47.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 70%
concat:generated      7.8s  ▇▇ 3%
ngAnnotate:dist       3.1s  ▇ 1%
copy:dist             3.2s  ▇ 1%
cdnify:dist          41.8s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 17%
uglify:generated      5.9s  ▇▇ 2%
Total 3m 59.6s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here's the error I was missing:

```
Parse Error: <head "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.requesting-page.com">
```

I commented out the line

```
<head "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.requesting-page.com">
```

From index.html and now it's building with out errors